# NPE when trying to initialize an internal class array

Tags: c#, class, computer-science, internal

i am trying to create an internal class inside a class and then initialize it as first value =0
i have this.

```
class Vehicle {
         internal class AGVSteps {
             public double X { get; set; }
             public double Y { get; set; }
         }

         private AGVSteps[] steps ;
         public AGVSteps [] Steps {
             get { return this.steps; }
         }

        public Vehicle() { //constructor
            this.steps = new AGVSteps[2000];
            this.steps[0].X = 0; //CRASHES HERE
            MessageBox.Show(this.steps[0].X + "");
            for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
               // this.steps[i].X = -1;
                //this.steps[i].Y = -1;
            }
        }

}
```

any idea ?i get a NPE error.Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`steps` is a container to `AGVSteps` objects. You need to initialize the `AGVSteps` itself

```
this.steps = new AGVSteps[2000];
for (int i = 0; i < steps.Length; i++) {
    steps[i] = new AGVSteps();
}
```